# How do I set up an AngularJS app using AWS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Would I use an EC2 instance and install a web server (such as Node.js) on it and then do everything as per usual or do I have to use something such as the AWS SDK for JavaScript?

(This is not a static AngularJS app and will be interacting with an application server)

Comment: Do your app use node js as server?

Comment: Yes it does, at least that is what I plan to use.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If your app only use angular js, then you can use [amazon s3 bucket](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html) to host your static website. Static website does not need any webserver. Here is the [tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/swh/website-hosting-intro.html) to get started.

If your app use nodejs as a server, then you need to login to your ec2 instance, and then install node js. Once installed, just run the app with node. Also make sure that you allow the nodejs port in security group setting of your instances.

I remember following this [blog](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2321-how-i-got-node-js-running-on-a-linux-micro-instance-using-amazon-ec2.htm), whenever I deployed node+angular app for the first time.

Node-Aws-Sdk is an ec2 library that is used for calling various aws services like Amazon S3, Amazon EC2, DynamoDB, and Amazon SWF. I don't think you need this unless you are interacting with these services in your nodejs code.

Comment: Thank you @ritesh_NITW that is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: the routing is a bit complicated to setup, so I will probable just use ec2

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to just put it in an S3 bucket and make it public. You are just serving javascript, you don't need to run it off a EC2 instance.

Comment: Okay thanks. I am not too familiar with S3 buckets. Would I be able to just serve JavaScript from one without the need for a web server?

Comment: yes, although the routing seems complicated to setup, so after a lot off faff I will probably move to ec2.